# Unable to get data from webservice to sencha touch list view

Tags: json, web-services, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a table called employee.  empid and empname are 2 fields.  I want to get data from that table through web service to sencha touch list view.  My web service is returning json data; I mean I converted the output to json.  My javascript code is as below

```
    Ext.data.JsonStore({
       proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
       url: 'http://localhost:58984/Service1.asmx/GetListData',  // werservicename.asmx/webMethodName
       headers: {
                   'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
       }),
       root: 'd',
       idProperty: 'empid',   // provide the unique id of the row
       fields: [empname]   // specify the array of fields
    });

    itemTpl: '{empname}'
```

But I am getting 2 errors:

1. `empname` is not defined
2. The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: *'Acsellerate.view.Main'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/view/Main.js*

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you pointed out exactly where the errors are occurring, but for nr1 the issue is probably that `fields: [empname]` should be `fields: ['empname']`.

Not sure if nr1 and nr2 are related, but if fixing the first error doesn't solve your problem you really need to show us your Main.js

Hope this helps